# Optimizing an ActiveRecord Query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm diving in to see if there is a way to make the follow method more performant.

It's currently being run as part of a background job and according to New Relic, it is the 2nd most time consuming job we have.

```
  def items_to_check
    items, opps = [Item, ItemOpportunity].map(&:arel_table)

    Item.where(
      items[:status].eq("current").and(items[:issue_date].lteq(maximum_allowed_issue_date))
      .or(items[:uuid].in(
        opps.where(opps[:invalidated_on].eq(nil)).project(opps[:product_uuid])
      ))
    )
  end
```

I'm not an expert at constructing ActiveRecord queries so if anyone could help break this down, that would be most helpful.

Comment: Please add your associations definitions, tables' schema and definitions of any related indexes.

Comment: Hey. I think that you can modify this part ( items[:uuid].in(
            opps.where(opps[:invalidated_on].eq(nil))) to JOIN items with oops, but I need your table schema to help you